SQL "EXCEPT" vs "WHERE NOT IN"
I would expect the following two queries to yield identical results; however, I have several instances where the first is empty while the second returns several hundred rows. How is this possible? Working in Azure Synapse using T-SQL
SELECT [value] FROM table_a
WHERE [value] NOT IN (SELECT [value] FROM table_b)

SELECT [value] FROM table_a
EXCEPT (SELECT [value] FROM table_b)


Can you provide concrete queries and any examples of what the second returns that the first does not?

I would suggest this is because value in table_b can be NULL, and thus returns no results. This is documented behaviour (see the big red box).

Dose this answer your question? SQL 0 results for 'Not In' and 'In' when row does exist

Agree with Thom A above and Joel Coehoorn below. A null value from table_b can lead to non-intuitive (but technically correct) result from the NOT IN operator. You might instead want SELECT value FROM table_a WHERE value NOT IN (SELECT value FROM table_b WHERE value IS NOT NULL), which excludes null values from the NOT IN list. See this db<>fiddle.

You're forgetting two options:
First, an exclusion join:
SELECT [value]
FROM table_a a
LEFT JOIN table_b b on a.[value] = b.[value]
WHERE b.[value] IS NULL

Second, NOT EXISTS():
SELECT [value] 
FROM table_a a
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM table_b b WHERE b.[VALUE] = a.[VALUE])

I like both of these better than either option presented. But of all four, this last option, with NOT EXISTS(), tends to perform better. Of course, you should also test to see what actually works best with your data and indexing.
But as to why the results are different... I'd expect to do with NULL comparisons, since NULL compared with itself is still false and otherwise confuse certain comparison operations. If table_b can have NULL values, that can definitely change things.

NULL compared to itself is not true... and also not false. Tri-valued logic and all that.

"I like better" is absolutely meaningless without naming a good reason. I dislike to misuse JOIN when we do not want to JOIN tables, but to check the existence. I highly like the EXCEPT option because of its perfect readability. But the question was not about that, so I wonder why you talk about it at all.
